# Excel Formula needed to find percentage of the data thats below a certain criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have data populated in cells E4 through CX4, all of which have a value between 0.00-7.99. I'm trying to find how many of the numbers in those cells are equal to or below 1.00 and what that percentage of the data that is.

**example:
data= 0.5, 0.66, 7.99, 1.0,
75% of this data is equal to, or below 1.00.

Question: How do I create an equation to do what I did in the example?

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Your wording suggests you pressed 93 number in just two cells. Please change your wording in a way that readers understand what you mean.

Comment: @r2d3 thanks for letting me know, I have edited my question. Hopefully that provides more clarity. Sorry, fairly new to excel formulas (as you can tell).

Comment: Did you delete your countif - question?

Comment: Welcome! `=COUNTIF(E4:CX4;"<=1")/COUNT(E4:CX4)` or if H4 contain 1.0 (as in your example) `=COUNTIF(E4:CX4;"<="&H4)/COUNT(E4:CX4)`, why not?

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:D1<=1)*1)/COUNT(A1:D1)
```

[image]